# How to enable CORS on Plesk 11.5?

Tags: centos, webserver, cors, plesk, contao

We are hosting websites on a server with CentOS and Plesk. For one of the websites we would like to enable CORS for a partner that wants to show specific content from our website on his own website.

How do I have to proceed for that and is CORS really save? I read some tutorials but they were to common to help me.

Again our server information:

Server: CentOS

Admin software: Plesk 11.5

CMS: Contao

Our partner only wants to grab content from our website, there is no other interaction needed (sending data over our website e.g.).

Thank´s for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom web server directives at domain's "Web Server Settings" page.

There is "Additional Apache directives" and "Additional nginx directives"

For example, to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header for nginx you need "add_header", as described in docs http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html it can be applied to http, virtual server or location.

So, you just can add following string at "Additional nginx directives":

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
```

[image: plesk nginx custom headers]